# How to use Promises with PapaParse?

Tags: javascript, promise, papaparse

PapaParse has an asynch callback function for its API. I was wondering how I can convert it to a promise. For eg:

```
Papa.parse(fileInput.files[0], {
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 38):

The basic pattern is

```
Papa.parsePromise = function(file) {
  return new Promise(function(complete, error) {
    Papa.parse(file, {complete, error});
  });
};
```

Then

```
Papa.parsePromise(fileInput.files[0]) .
  then(function(results) { console.log(results); });
```

Comment: This works, and thank you, but I don't understand what complete and error are doing. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Kyouma `complete` is the Promise's `resolve` function and `error` is the `reject` function, they are being used as the callback functions on `complete` and `error` for `Papa.parse`.

Comment: Nice, great job!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use Async/Await...

```
someButtonClicked = async rawFile => {
    const parseFile = rawFile => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        papa.parse(rawFile, {
          complete: results => {
            resolve(results.data);
          }
        });
      });
    };
    let parsedData = await parseFile(rawFile);
    console.log("parsedData", parsedData);
  };
```

Comment: You should move the `parseFile` "helper" function outside of `someButtonClicked`, it's really independent from the use of `async`/`await` there.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess it can be used with all kind of variations, I am providing the string to parse although you can use it with file path or url :

```
  const parseData = (content) => {
  let data;
  return new Promise( (resolve) => {
    Papa.parse(content, {
      header: true,
      delimiter: ',',
      dynamicTyping: true,
      complete: (results) => {
        data = results.data;
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
    
  });
};
```

Comment: This is plain wrong and does not work when the `complete` callback is asynchronous. You resolve the promise before `data` gets assigned.

Comment: ohh sorry that was typo from my side

Comment: But if you do it properly, you don't need that `let data` at all