# Waiting for function with Promises all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I am using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901255/wait-for-two-or-more-files-to-load-with-papa-parse) to load a bunch of .csv files. Once these are loaded, I then want to render a react component. I have posted my method below that is inside a datareader.js. I am trying to figure out how to best call this method from a separate component that calls this and waits for it to complete before proceeding.

```
export async function LoadParkingTicketsData() {
  let urls = [
    "./data/2016.csv",
    "data/2017.csv"
  ];

  Promise.all(
    //pass array of promises to Promise.all
    urls //you have an array of urls
      .map(
        //map urls to promises created with parse
        (url) =>
          new Promise(
            (
              resolve,
              reject //create one promise
            ) =>
              Papa.parse(url, {
                download: true,
                complete: resolve, //resolve the promise when complete
                error: reject, //reject the promise if there is an error
              })
          )
      )
  )
    .then(function (results) {
      **console.log(results[0]);** // log result from file 1
      console.log(results[1]); // log result from file 2
    })
    .catch(
      //log the error
      (err) => console.warn("Something went wrong:", err)
    );
}
```

I am assuming I will have to do something inside useEffect() but no matter how I call this method, the execution continues and ends up calling ** line after. Can someone show me how to best do this so the data load happens and until then it waits.

```
export function TimeOfDayTickets() {

  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div className="App">Loading...</div>;
  }
  return <Line options={options} data={chartData} />;
}
```

Comment: You have to `await` your async processes in the function, otherwise the function returns a promise that resolves right away, before the async processes have completed. So put `await` before  `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want to do? let me know if that helps

```
 export function TimeOfDayTickets() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


  useEffect(() => {
    LoadParkingTicketsData().then((res) => {
      setData(res);
      
    }).finally(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    })
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div className="App">Loading...</div>;
  }
  return <Line options={options} data={data} />;
}
```

Note: `finally` will run even if the function is unable to get the data, therefore, `isLoading` will be set to `false` and the component `Line` will render, if you are passing the `data` state to `Line`, you should handle inside it what happens if there is no data, for example, rendering a message like "No data available" or something.

Comment: I see the same behavior with this code. That is setData(res) is called before LoadParkingTicketsData has had a chance to complete.

Comment: Try to add await on your Promise.all, see if that changes something