# Papa.parse Complex promise

Tags: javascript, promise, papaparse

I have tried to use the solution at:
[How to use Promises with PapaParse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375531/how-to-use-promises-with-papaparse)
to use Papa.parse with a promise, instead of using the inbuilt callback function. Unfortunately my configuration requirement is more complex than the given example as follows

```
Papa.parsePromise = function(file) {
  return new Promise(function(complete, error) {
    Papa.parse(file, {
        delimiter: "",
        newline: "",
        download: true, 
        error,
        complete: function(results){
    var tArray=[];
    var data = results.data;
    var temp = data.length;
    var filledRowCounter=0;
    filePresentMarker=1;
        for(var i=0;i<temp;i++){
            var row = data[i];
            if (row[0]!==""){
            filledRowCounter++; 
            tArray.push(row);
            }
         }
}   
        });
  });
};


Papa.parsePromise("Data/tables.csv")
.then(function(results) { 
  console.log(results); 
  });
```

The code filling tArray works fine. However, nothing is passed back to the .then function, so nothing is output to the console.log

Comment: Thanks - that worked fine (after taking out the error line)

Answer (score 2):

You're never calling the `resolve` callback of the promise in your code. However, when taking [that code you found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31375659/1048572) you should keep the logic within the `new Promise` constructor minimal, and when you have a "*more complex configuration requirement*" you should just put that extra logic in a `then` callback from which you can `return` a value:

```
function parsePromise(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Papa.parse(file, {
      delimiter: "",
      ewline: "",
      download: true,
      complete: resolve,
      error: reject
    });
  }).then(({data}) => {
    var tArray = [];
    var filePresentMarker = 1;
    for (const row of data) {
      if (row[0] !== "") {
        tArray.push(row);
      }
    }
    var filledRowCounter = tArray.length;
    return tArray; // or something
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  })
}
```