# Map object not setting values after execution of function

Tags: javascript, csv, dictionary, parsing, papaparse

I have a function below where the purpose is to parse multiple local csv files. For each parsed csv file, I then grab 1-5 random elements. Since the CSV parser outputs the data in a nested array structure (`[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]`), I further process the data and extract the individual array elements to push into the `final` array.

My final goal is to update the values in the `types` map by passing in the respective arrays for each of its keys

```js
let health = createHealthData();
console.log(health, 'final output')

function createHealthData() {
  let types = new Map();
  types.set('allergies', '');
  types.set('medications', '')
  let start = 1;
  let limit = 5;

  for (let key of types.keys()) {
    let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (limit - start + 1) + start); // Generates random numbers between start and limit
    let file = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, `${key}.csv`))

    Papa.parse(file, {
      header: false,
      complete: (results) => {
        let first = []
        let data = results.data;

        let final = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= randNum; i++) {
          first.push(data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)])
        }

        first.forEach((x) => {
          x.forEach((y) => {
            final.push(y)
          })
        })
        types.set(key, final);
        console.log(types);
      }
    })
  }
  return types;
}
```

My function parses and processes the csv files fine, but it refuses to update the existing keys in the map once I return the `types` map

For instance, my output at `console.log(types)` gives me:

```
Map(2) {
   allergies => ['Banana Allergy'],
   medications => ['Opana ER', 'Atrovent HFA']
}
```

which is what I intend to pass out of the function.

However, upon viewing the `health` variable after the function finishes executing, the output is:

```
Map(2) {'allergies' => '', 'medications' => ''} final output
```

as if the line `types.set(key,final)` never executed at the end of the function. I'm struggling to find what the source of this bug is and based on the scope of the `types` variable in the function, I'm not seeing where it might be overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Papa.parse is asynchronous:
https://www.papaparse.com/docs

> "Doesn't return anything. Results are provided asynchronously to a
> callback function."

Since you `return types` at the end, you won't get the proper values yet due to the asynchronous nature of the execution (i.e. return types happens first, followed by the parsing complete callback).

There's a similar question that describes different ways of handling Papa.parse: [How to use Promises with PapaParse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375531/how-to-use-promises-with-papaparse)

Answer (score 1):

As i understand the function return without waiting Papa.parse callback so try solutions from [How to use Promises with PapaParse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375531/how-to-use-promises-with-papaparse) to wait for the complete callback to finish then return the types